# System.InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId "$T" for type "$T". The same schemaId is already used for type "$T"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have some models that are polymorphic and recursive with generics. I get this SwaggerGen error when launching my ASP.NET Core Web API project and I'm not sure what's going on.

Error:

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate Operation for action - ExampleOrg.WebApi.Controllers.ExampleController.GetExampleAsync (ExampleOrg.WebApi). See inner exception
> ---> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate schema for type - ExampleOrg.Abstractions.Models.Example. See inner exception
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId "$T" for type "$T". The same schemaId is already used for type "$T"
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaRepository.RegisterType(Type type, String schemaId)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForMember(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, DataProperty dataProperty) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<GenerateConcreteSchema>b__3() at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(DataContract allowedTypeDataContract)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.ToList() at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GeneratePolymorphicSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, IEnumerable`1 knownTypesDataContracts)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForType(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo, ApiParameterRouteInfo routeInfo)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateArraySchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__1()
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForMember(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, DataProperty dataProperty)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__3()
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<GenerateConcreteSchema>b__3() at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(DataContract allowedTypeDataContract)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.ToList() at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GeneratePolymorphicSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, IEnumerable`1 knownTypesDataContracts)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForType(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo, ApiParameterRouteInfo routeInfo)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateArraySchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__1()
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForMember(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, DataProperty dataProperty)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__3()
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<GenerateConcreteSchema>b__3() at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__3()
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<GenerateConcreteSchema>b__3() at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(DataContract allowedTypeDataContract)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.ToList() at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GeneratePolymorphicSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, IEnumerable`1 knownTypesDataContracts)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForMember(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, DataProperty dataProperty)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__3()
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForType(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo, ApiParameterRouteInfo routeInfo) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type type, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo, ApiParameterRouteInfo routeInfo) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type type, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo, ApiParameterRouteInfo routeInfo) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreateResponseMediaType(ModelMetadata modelMetadata, SchemaRepository schemaRespository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<GenerateResponse>b__2(String contentType) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateResponse(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, String statusCode, ApiResponseType apiResponseType)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateResponses(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperation(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperation(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerDocumentWithoutFilters(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerAsync(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I have added `JsonDerivedType` attributes to the base abstract class. In unit tests of the models, JSON serialization and deserialization are working fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need to see the code that is provoking this huge error msg, even before dissecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround.

```cs
services
    .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        // ...

        var i = 0;

        c.CustomSchemaIds
        (
            type => type.IsGenericType 
                ? $"{type.Name[..^2]}<{string.Join(", ", type.GenericTypeArguments.Select(arg => arg.Name))}>"
                : type.FullName is null
                ? $"{type}_{i++}"
                : type.Name
        );
        
        // ...
    });
```